# How to make the Google Cloud Platform App EngineStandard access non-secure endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

From the front-end app that built from App Engine Standard, we have a print request send to http://70.53.4.12:9100 which is a raw printer port and it works on the locally development box and just not working in the Cloud, it compliant about the endpoint is non-secure, how can we bypass this and let Cloud accept this endpoint as HTTP only like an exception.

Here is the error message showing in console.

VM9:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-dev.domain.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://70.53.4.12:9100/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.(anonymous)

The IP 70.53.4.12 is public accessible, so I can send print request from my home to the printer sitting in my office through port forwarding, but can't do it from the Google Cloud Platform App Engine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your browser is displaying this error. If you load a web page over HTTPS, you must load all content over HTTPS. This is a security feature. Change your endpoint to support HTTPS. Otherwise, don't use a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the SSL check means your application becomes vulnerable to both man-in-the-middle attacks and DNS hijacking attacks.
Furthermore, HTTPS does more than simply "encrypt credentials", it's also a method to ensure authenticity: is the server I'm talking to really who they say they are. 
Now I'm not sure about the nature of your application data, but malformed data can be used as an attack vector.

I would recommend keeping SSL on and figuring out how to properly configure the endpoint instead.
I found this document for your reference that indicates how to use ssl/tls for secure printing[1]

[1] https://www.novell.com/documentation/open-enterprise-server-2018/iprint_lx/data/aaxguq6.html?view=print